# Adding url preview thumbnail for my react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, thumbnails

I want to add a thumbnail for my react app, so that when I paste it in Teams for instance I will have a preview same as below:
[image]

I have tried using `react-helmet` with no success:

```
<Helmet meta={[
{ property: 'og:title', content: "my-custom-title" },
{ property: 'og:type', content: "website" },
{ property: 'og:url', content: "http://localhost:4201/immunology-ACR" },
{ property: 'og:description', content: "my-custom-desc" },
{ property: 'og:image', content: "some image" },
]}>
</Helmet>
```

Still, no preview
[image]

not even sure that is the right solution. If anyone can help it would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is a background network request to get that meta data. And it won't be able to query your localhost for it. Once you publish you can test on a staging environment for the correct values.